# Basic Question about absolutely continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

My question is maybe elementary but I'm having troubles with it. I have a function $f$ absolutely continuous in (a,c) and in (c,b), $f$ continuous in $c$. Is $f$ absolutely continuous in (a,b)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct! All your have to prove is that if $f$ is continuous at c then it is absolutely continuous at c. Then,consider a random $x_0$ that belongs to (a,c) and prove that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: But absolute continuity is a definition over intervals, how do I prove this in one point?